# Get that a fragment is first item in stackk

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity that manages a list of fragments. Each Time I want to add a fragment to the stack i call

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.layout, fragment, tag);
 ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

Then I constantly push/pop different fragments on and off the stack. When I push them off i call

```
  getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

Does anyone know of a way for the Fragment to know that it is now the top fragment in the stack? i.e. I have a fragments on a stack in order of A B C D. If i pop D off the stack, is there anyway for C to know that it is currently on the top of the stack?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ft.addToBackStack(null);, set a name instead of null. You can then use this to identify a backstack entry.

i.e.

```
BackStackEntry currentBackStack = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1);
currentBackStack.getName();//your identifier
```

This gets the last item in the backstack, and gets the name of that backstack entry.
You can do this in each fragment, and check if the name matches.

Comment: Right, I know how to do that, but then how do I notify the fragment (that I have the name of) that it is currently on top?

Comment: You could keep a reference to your fragments. The code above determines which fragment is current, so then you can just call a method on that fragment.


Or you can do a findFragmentById, or findFragmentByTag, to get the fragment you want, and the call a method on that fragment.


Alternatively, all your fragments could extend a base fragment class with a method called something like onFragmentOnTop. Then you don't need to worry about determining which fragment is current. Just call  the method on the fragment returned by findFragmentById, and let the fragment handle the logic after that.